# what is difference in requst.getContextPath() and basePath? Special in Cluster

Tags: java, web

sometimes we use like this to include a JS file:

`script src="request.getContextPath()/xx/xx.js"`

and sometimes we use like this to include a JS file:

```
<%
  String basePath = request.getScheme() + "://"+ request.getServerName() + ":" 
    +  request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();
%>
script src="<%=basePath%>/xx/xx.js"
```

then what is the difference?

Special in Cluster,can Cause some errors?

thank you for your answer!!!

Comment: both are mean to load js file dynamically. I don't see any difference or possible cause of error meanwhile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard concept of base path in java web. Context path is the path of context that is shared for all java servlets. It is the path of the web app. It normally equals '/'  + yourWebAppName. It  can be empty too.

In your case.  I think it is ok to use both way.

Answer (score 0):

First example constructs a relative path to your app, for `http://example.com/myApp` it would translate to `/myApp/xx/xx.js`

Second example constructs an absolute path that includes everything, resulting in `http://example.com/myApp/xx/xx.js`